# ejabberd: prevent the use of messages with subject by spammers

Tags: spam, xmpp, ejabberd

Recently there have been noticed a sudden surge in Jabber/XMPP spammers activity. Spammers not only manage to send a regular messages to users, like this:

[image: Message]

but also a some kind of announcement message, **each** of which opens in a **separate** window, which is frustratingly annoying. Here is one of such windows:

[image: Announcement]

It is been suggested by a user here, that these are just a regular messages, but with a `subject`. Is there a way to disable such messages server wide?

Comment: Best way to find out is probably to get an XML capture of those spam messages. Only then you can figure out what they are.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not announcement. It seems to be standard message with subject. You simply need to find the abuse user and block their account and tighten control and validation on account registration. It is for example a good idea to block in-band registration and handle registration through a web form.

Comment: There are plenty of such malicious users with disposable usernames. Are there a method to disable such messages with subject server wide?

Comment: Message with subject are just standard XMPP messages. Please see the XMPP RFC, subject is a valid optional field: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-syntax-subject Even if you write a custom module, spammers will still be able to send messages without subject. You need to tighten your control on account registration.

Comment: I am okay for now for regular spam messages, what I seek is to how to disable these annoying spam messages in separate windows. By the way, there is nothing to do with account registration on my server, since all spammers are from other servers. On the screenshot provided it is shown, that this particular one came from `kdetalk.net`. I've blocked this JID of course, but it is just a disposable one.

Comment: What I am saying, is that it is a regular spam message.

Comment: I understood. But seems it is not as regular as a _true_ regular, since it has a subject (even empty) and always opens in a separate window. What I (and probably others since the question is already upvoted and starred) seek is a way to disable such _messages with subjects_ server wide.

Comment: There is not such feature to block message with subject in ejabberd. You need to write a plugin to filter out message based on ejabberd packet_filter API.

Comment: Okay, Mickaël, thanks for your answers, as far as I understood, you are a major contributor to `ejabberd`, may I ask a question in this regard? The spam problem arose couple of months ago, and the particular _messages with subject_ are already a pain to many users. They are used **only** by spammers to distract users. The problem is hot and it is keep getting worse. Should we, `ejabberd` administrators wait for the official possibility to disable these kind of messages in ejabberd's config? Or the only option is to wait till someone write a filter, which you suggested in the previous comment?

Comment: yes, you need someone to write it. I may give it a go when I have some time but do not hold your breath, not sure when I can do it

Comment: Okay, thanks, if you'll find time to do it eventually, that'll be great.